# HTML tag replacement with JS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following HTML string which I'm building using JS with help from https://jonsuh.com/blog/javascript-templating-without-a-library/:

```
htmlString= '<select id="DATE" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="FULLNAME" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="STREET" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="CITY" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="STATE" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="ZIP" type="text" value="myvalue"/><select id="FIRST" type="text" value="myvalue"/>'
```

I noticed that No closing select tag was produced and i decided to substitute in in using:

```
htmlString.replace(/\/>/g,">options_go_here</option>");
```

The regex looks right to me :  https://regex101.com/r/gJLrhR/2

However I see no change in the string. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you assign the new string back to `htmlString`? Also, don't even try to [parse HTML with Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/).

Comment: Hm, templating HTML with strings and regular expression doesn't really sound like a very good idea, and brings b̤͖͢a̠̹̥͘cḵ͓̳̣͘ ͡h̲̀ò̩̞͖̮ŕ̻̦͔r̙̣̘̮̦̩̀i͔͙̦̼̱̳b̳̰̫͉l̤͠e̳͚̯͕͈ ̩͘m̟̤̼e͕m̴̫̲o̥͇͍̖ͅr̞͜i̢̭͍̬̟̥ḙ̷̼̬̰̝̠s̱͍̜̱͈̞
 of Tony the Pony

Comment: Derek You were right, thank you!

Comment: I'm working with apps script on the server side, which does not have support for HTML, so I have to build the HTML dynamically using strings.